# UICollectionViewFlowLayout Changing minimumInteritemSpacing for the last row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

So I'm not sure what needs to be posted considering a lot of the formatting of my UICollectionView is done in a storyboard - I'm using the flow layout as mentioned in the title and I have the minInteritemSpacing set to 10. I have colored each of the cells backgroundColor to green and set the interlineSpacing to 0 to help see the issue. It appears on the last line that the interitemSpacing is wrong (check out the picture below), even if I have more than 2 items on it. 
[image: Misaligned Last Row]

UPDATE: I realized the only real customization I do is resize the first cell of each row to be wider. If I take this away the issue goes away (if I take away my following implementation:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    long modder = indexPath.item % nBytesPerRow;
    if (modder == 0) {
        return lineHeaderSize;
    }
    return ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout).itemSize;
}
```

)

Thanks

Dan

Comment: How am I supposed to include code when the formatting is done in the storyboard? Should I post my completely generic UICollectionViewController? I really don't see how that would help...